# What's wrong with my for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am making a game using lite-C (exactly same syntax as C). and I cannot make this loop work.
It gives me an error at this line at compilation.


`for(int i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3)`

I have an array with the information of where to create the enemies.
the array contains the x,y,z coordinates.

cantenemigu is the amount of enemies that there are in the array.

With this loop I would get the information of each enemy and create it.

[EDIT]
The answers didn't work. I added the ; acsidently while writing the post.

Maybe the problem is somewhere else;

Here is the hole part.

```
int cantenemigu = 3;
var posenemigu[] = {-900, 550, -10, -1100, 1600, -10, 70, 1680, 20};
void load_enemigunan()
{ 
 for(int i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3) 
 {
  ent_create("targetr.mdl",vector(posenemigu[i],
             posenemigu[i + 1],
             posenemigu[i + 2]),NULL);
 } 
}
```

This is the code if I don't add the <br>

I solved it.

this worked.

```
int i
for(i = 0; i < 3*cantenemigu; i += 3)
{
    ent_create("targetr.mdl",vector(posenemigu[i],
                                                posenemigu[i + 1],
                                                posenemigu[i + 2]),NULL);
}
```

In C# it doesn't have be declared before. I assumed it was also so in C. (or maybe it's a bug in the compiler).

Comment: May I ask what the error message was?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Mind pasting it here?

Comment: @ChaosPandion The compiler gave a syntax error. Sorry I forgot to write it?

Comment: the <br> is he code isn't in. Some times I use html to format the queastions

Comment: Could you edit the post to 1) make the code match exactly what's in your program (you say the semi-colons are accidental but they're still there, and there's a <br> for some reason), 2) include the compiler's error message?

Comment: @Aaron de Windt: RE: EDIT: You still have that semicolon there. Are you sure that's not the problem? Don't use html to format your code.

Comment: @Aaron: can you at least edit your question so the source matches what you're trying to compile? And then write a less shitty title?

Comment: wrap your code in a [code] block please...unless...your source code was all on one line??

Comment: it is in a code block. I don't know what is happening with the code.

Comment: It could be a typedef.  It's really impossible to say exactly what the problem is without more information.

Comment: @Mark. It can hold numbers with decimals. The coordinates must be a var

Comment: It only sais syntax error at that line. nothing more.

Comment: can you show us the declaration for `ent_create`?

Comment: ent_create(STRING* filename, VECTOR* position, function);

Comment: And the declaration of vector?

Comment: Which line does the syntax error appear on? What's the return type of vector()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this: (note what I've done is move the declaration of `i` outside the `for` loop.

```
int cantenemigu = 3;
var posenemigu[] = {-900, 550, -10, -1100, 1600, -10, 70, 1680, 20};
void load_enemigunan(){ 
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3){
         ent_create("targetr.mdl",vector(posenemigu[i],
             posenemigu[i + 1],
             posenemigu[i + 2]),NULL);
     } 
}
```

Comment: You posted it just 5 min to late. This solved the problem. Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: @Aaron, no, this isn't a compiler bug, it's standard C syntax (not C99 syntax which would allow what you originally wrote). FWIW, if this solved the problem the etiquette here is to accept the answer.

Comment: yes I know. sorry. I don't talk english. sorry if it sounded bad. thanks for the answer. Wath I wanted to say is that I just solved it the same way.

Comment: C99 is standard C. It's just that many implementations don't conform to modern standards.

Comment: @R what I meant was it was C90, as opposed to C99...what gcc, for instance will call just plain "C".

Answer (score 7):

`for (int i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3)`

There should not be any `;` after `i += 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the 3rd `;`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis for your call to `vector`.

```
ent_create(
    "targetr.mdl",
    vector(
        posenemigu[i], 
        posenemigu[i + 1], 
        posenemigu[i + 2],
        NULL
);
```

Comment: @Aaron - Please post the exact error the compiler is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < (cantenemigu * 3); i += 3;)
```

What is the error? That last semicolon shouldn't be there.

What is the body of the loop?

What type of variable is `cantenemigu`? Can it be coerced to `int`?

Comment: I really hope `cantenemigu` is a domain specific term because it looks like gibberish to me.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I speak papiamentu. It stands for cantidad di enemigu (amount of enemies).